# How to efficiently concatenate many computed dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

Using distributed scheduler I'm ingesting data from many binary source files which don't lend themselves to Dask's provided methods (e.g. `read_csv()`, `read_parquet()`, etc), and for each binary file I'm producing a pandas dataframe (within a delayed-decorated function).

In my infancy with Dask I'm trying to understand how to efficiently concatenate all the `pandas.dataframe`s into a single `dask.dataframe` for further processing. This `dask.dataframe` will be larger than memory, though in my testing so far I'm using reduced data volumes.

My code is resulting in only a single worker being active, and the process taking a very long time, even though the graph visualization seems to suggest parallel operation. I don't understand why.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

def process_data_ddf(filenames):
    narrowband_ddf_list = []
    for f in filenames:
        tdms_data = read_a_file(f)
        narrowband_df = calculate_narrowband(tdms_data["metadata"], tdms_data["data"])
        narrowband_ddf = dd.from_delayed(narrowband_df)
        narrowband_ddf_list.append(narrowband_ddf)
    narrowbands_ddf = dd.concat(narrowband_ddf_list)
    return narrowbands_ddf

result = dask.compute(process_data_ddf(filenames))
```

I tried modifying this code such that I just collect a list of a pandas dataframes and call `pd.concat()` at the end (code below). With this, all workers are active and the process completes quickly, but I don't believe this will scale well.

```
def process_data_df(filenames):
    narrowband_df_list = []
    for f in filenames:
        tdms_data = read_a_file(f)
        narrowband_df = calculate_narrowband(tdms_data["metadata"], tdms_data["data"])
        narrowband_df_list.append(narrowband_df)
    return narrowband_df_list

result = pd.concat(dask.compute(process_data_df(filenames))[0])
```

`process_data_ddf` graph:
[image]

`process_data_df` graph:
[image]

Most of the docs seem to focus on aggregating data on import using something like `dd.read_csv('myfiles.*.csv')`. What's the best way to approach this for my use case?

CLARIFICATIONS:

- `calculate_narrowband()` and `read_a_file()` have `@dask.delayed` decorators.
- All dataframes I'm trying to concatenate have identical columns and no index duplicates
- Dataframe indeces are datetimes, I don't care about sort.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the purpose of `from_delayed()` and now realize it can accept a list of `delayed`.

This appears to perform nicely from initial testing:

```
def process_data_ddf(filenames):
    narrowband_df_list = []
    for f in filenames:
        tdms_data = read_a_file(f)
        narrowband_df = calculate_narrowband(tdms_data["metadata"], tdms_data["data"])
        narrowband_df_list.append(narrowband_df)
    narrowband_ddf = dd.from_delayed(narrowband_df_list)
    return narrowband_ddf
```